# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.classloader.Handler$ClassLoaderURLConnection incompatible with java.net.JarURLConnection

Tags: java, jar, resources, websphere

How do i list the contents of a directory with wsjar files?

The code below is not working for WebSphere but does work for JBoss:

```
Enumeration<URL> en = getClass( ).getClassLoader( ).getResources( "com/myjars" );

while( en.hasMoreElements( ) ) {

    URL url = en.nextElement( );

    if( url.toString( ).startsWith( "jar:file:" ) || url.toString( ).startsWith( "wsjar:file:" ) ) {

        JarFile jarFile = ( (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection( ) ).getJarFile( );

        Enumeration<JarEntry> eje = jarFile.entries( );

        while( eje.hasMoreElements( ) ) {
            JarEntry jarEntry = eje.nextElement( );

            System.out.println( jarEntry.getName( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

On WebSphere, i got:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.classloader.Handler$ClassLoaderURLConnection  incompatible with java.net.JarURLConnection

Comment: Have you checked to see if one is a subclass of the other?

Comment: (You can't convert an object from one type to another by simply casting it.)

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know why IBM has to do things like this.

Comment: Websphere is a nigthmare for web development!

Comment: I'm no great fan of WS either, but this sort of problem occurs many places in Java, often between various Sun/Oracle components.

Answer (score 0):

You might try opening by stripping the `jar:file:` from the URL and using a [`ZipFile` type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) instead, since you're not really interested in the jar as a jar, but rather the files within the jar (which is just a zip file).

So, `"jar:file:///foo/bar/baz.jar"` becomes `"/foo/bar/baz.jar"` which you pass to the [`ZipFile(String)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#ZipFile%28java.lang.String%29)